# After class toggle, how do I make this effect to stay on users browser forever?

Tags: javascript

Whenever user on browser clicks on closeBtn. How do I make the effect stay forever on his website until he changes his IP address or browser? I want the class none to be not displayed on his view all the time.

```
 let cookiebox = document.getElementById('cookie-box');
  let closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn');

  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    cookiebox.classList.toggle("none")
  })
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the `none` to go away when the user clicks it again? If so you could use `cookiebox.classList.add("none");`

Comment: Store the info that they already clicked, in a cookie or localStorage, so that you can read it back from there. Then read that info when the page loads, and hide the box when applicable.

Comment: After clicking closeBtn, it hides a popup box. I want the popup box to never appear again.

Comment: How do I store this in local storage?

Comment: You can use `Window.localStorage` for save and load from local storage. you can read [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest storing a closed flag in `sessionStorage`. Data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends...

> - A page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores.
> - Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.
> - Opening multiple tabs/windows with the same URL creates sessionStorage for each tab/window.
> - Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears objects in sessionStorage.

More about session storage can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

A rough example of this implementation would be:

```js
let cookiebox = document.getElementById('cookie-box');
let closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn');

function closeCookieBox() {
    cookiebox.classList.add("none");
}

if (sessionStorage.getItem("closed_cookie_box")) {
    closeCookieBox();
}

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    closeCookieBox();
    sessionStorage.setItem("closed_cookie_box", true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed